# Header with login/log out logic in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform

I am new to web programming and especially to programming with GWT.
I am creating my application with Eclipse (Java) using GWT, GAE and GWT-Platform.
My application has "Header" "Main-content" and "Footer",

- Header: is a widget that has a login/sign up links
- Main-Content: is presenting different presenters- login page, sign out page, home page (of user after login).

I would like to change the "Header" after the user is login (to hide the login/sign up links and show the user name instead), click on the user name will give a drop down menu of: log out, edit profile, ...

**How should i implement the Header?**

Should Header be a presenter and not a widget? (because i have to add to it logic)
Should i use event bus to fire event from the sing in presenter to the Header Widget?

i hope i was clear, thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Igor,
header should have View and Presenter. Presenter can subscribe to EventBus and change corresponding links on Login/Logout event. Yes, you have to use EventBus.

Generally, login or logout events can be fired from anywhere place of your app, for example on RPC calls which required authorization. If session is timed out, such rpc call must fire logout event and header links must be updated.

In my point of view, login window should have View and Presenter too, it Presenter must handle  login procedure and fire login event.

Comment: Thanks for the response! It leads me to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745194/gwt-platform-several-nested-presenters-in-one-global-presenter