# GWT-Platform Several nested presenters in one global presenter

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-platform

I am building an web application (Java) using GWT-Platform MVP model.
I have one Global presenter that has "Header", "Main-content" and "Footer".

"Main-content" - is presenting different presenters- login page, sign out page, home page...
"Header" - is a widget.

**I want to convert the Header from widget to View-Presenter how should i do it?**
In other words how my "Global Presenter" will contain two different presenters?

I tried the following answears but nothing seems to work for me:
1. [Nested presenters with GWTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578123/nested-presenters-with-gwtp)
2. http://toolongdidntread.com/gwt/using-nested-presenters-with-gwtp/

I am new to web programming and especially to programming with GWT, so maybe i need some more clear examples, or some deep guides.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Your question was answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578123/nested-presenters-with-gwtp

Answer (score 2):

Do watch Dani's GWTP Course on Youtube. It helps a lot. It has worked for me.